# Coldfusion MySQL Query within a Query

Tags: mysql, date, coldfusion, cfquery

I am trying to retrieve records that falls in specific year and month from a full set of records retrieve for a particular user.  Firstly, the field in question itemdate is MySql type Datetime (e.g. 2016-08-15 20:00:25).  There are 4 rows of records for a user:

```
2016-08-15 20:00:25
2015-06-01 20:25:05
2016-08-15 20:26:00
2016-08-15 23:30:35
```

These records for a particular user are retrieved by:

```
<cfquery datasource="userdatbase"name="reportlist">
select itemid, itemdate, itemvalue
from itemlib
where userid = '#currentuserid#'
</cfquery>
```

The current year and month is determined by:

```
<cfset thisyear = #Year(Now())#>
<cfset thismonth = #Month(Now())#>
```

Now filter the original query and get only those from current year and month:

```
    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail"> 
        select itemid, itemdate, itemvalue
        from reportlist
        where year(itemdate) = #thisyear#
        and month(itemdate) = #thismonth#
    </cfquery>
```

I am getting the following error:

Error Executing Database Query.

**Query Of Queries syntax error.**
Encountered "year. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition,

I have tried to do this instead:

```
    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail"> 
        select itemid, itemdate, itemvalue
        from reportlist
        where #year(reportlist.itemdate)# = #thisyear#
        and #month(reportlist.itemdate)# = #thismonth#
    </cfquery>
```

which will get rid of the error.  However, I got all 4 rows of records in the *detail* query instead of the expected 3.  I do not expect the **2015-06-01 20:25:05** record to be selected, but it does.  I am scratching my head over this.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure month/year functions are supported though the type of connection/driver you're using?  Month/Year appear to be supported by MySQL so I don't think the engine is having trouble parsing the query.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: *However, I got all 4 rows* Because the SQL query is not doing what you think it is... You are doing a comparison of two literal values, like `WHERE 1 = 1`. It will always be true (or false) for every row in the query.

Comment: What happens to your page if you put a date range in the original database query?

Comment: @DanBracuk I need to check if there is anything for the user.  So I didn't put a date range in the database query.  I only execute the QofQ only if something returned from the user.  I believe the date range will work on the original database query.  The problem is with the QofQ.  I want to prevent hitting the database again if there are records returned a user.

Comment: Q of Q is not always a better option than multiple db hits.  If you are dealing with large amounts of data, you could run into memory problems.  That may or may not be the case in your situation.  Another option you have is to do your check with a `select count(*)` query.  It's all an inexact science.

Comment: @DanBracuk  Thanks for the great advise.  I think I will consider it.  The number of records can be huge as the records will be stored for 2 years for each user.  I am thinking of caching it for 5 minute on each query and allowing the user to look thru different months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A coldfusion Query of Queries (QofQ) does not have the full functionality of a dbms. `year()` is not supported in  QofQ syntax.

Your second query is syntactically correct because it is passing in the value of the `reportlist.itemdate`, which will be the value of `itemdate` in the *first row* of the query `reportlist` (assuming you are not looping over `reportlist`). ColdFusion interprets this as comparing two literal values instead of comparing the row values in the query.

Alternatively you could set a variable (`fromDate`) to the first date of the month you want, then filter your query where the item date is `>=` the fromDate and `<` fromDate plus 1 month. See below:

```
<!--- set fromDate to the first date of the month --->
<cfset fromDate = createDate(thisyear, thismonth, 1) />
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail"> 
    select itemid, itemdate, itemvalue
    from reportlist
    where itemdate >= <cfqueryparam value="#fromDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
          and itemdate < <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('m', 1, fromDate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
</cfquery>
```

This accomplishes the same thing by using comparators supported in a ColdFusion QoQ.

Some helpful documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html

Comment: Thank you @beloitdavisja  I did not know that YEAR and MONTH would not work on QofQ but I thought MySQL also has these functions.  Why MySQL function did not kick in in my first QofQ attempt?   I also did not know that CF won't work on individual row values because it returned 4 rows not one. If I had loop it wouldn't it return 16 rows (4x4)?  This is my first time using QofQ and it drove me crazy.

Comment: @Jack MySQL does have these functions. However, a Query of Queries *does not* run in MySQL. A QofQ is most often used to filter or modify the resultset of a database query in memory. It is a powerful tool, but can be frustrating since it has its own rules and limited syntax. It is not a full-featured database query language like MySQL and does not use any functionality from these database query languages, even if the resultset originates from a MySQL database.

Comment: *I need to check if there is anything for the user* Also it is worth noting you may not need multiple queries (or a QoQ) at all. Is there a reason you cannot use a JOIN on itemlib and reportlist, and filter it on userID?

Comment: @Leigh Thanks Leigh.  The reportlist is a query came out of the query from itemlib on the user.  I am not sure what I will get out of the JOIN after the initial query on the user?

Comment: @Jack - Hm... then what does querying twice buy you? Why not just apply the date filters in the initial db query?

Comment: @Leigh I need the first pass to check if there is any record at all for the user.  if there is none, I simply display a message telling the user there is no records at all for the item.  If I simply display the current date record and there is none, the user may try different dates, and find nothing.  But he will hit the db many times.

Comment: @Jack - Hitting the db is not always a bad thing, because you do not really save much if you are still pulling X number of records (ie 50,100,1000) from the database every time, and if there is no match, the records are just discarded. Adding a subselect with a `count(*)` would probably be more efficient.  Also, you might look into caching and/or show the users a range of what dates they have available to cut down on the "guessing" factor. All depends on the app...

Comment: @Leigh I am planning on implement what Dan Bracuk suggested. Use the 'Select count(*)' on the first query (and cache the count for 5 min. instead of all the user's record)   Then do the db query firstly on the current date, then subsequent queries on different dates.  Will that work better?   (The program calls itself I cache the count so that it doesn't check the count again every time the user selects a different date.)

Comment: @Leigh This may be a stupid question - If I created a cache for a user's data, is this cache available to the user only or all users on site?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you believe this *is* an issue or is this just premature optimization? Generally a simple count(*) is not that expensive and could even be performed in the same query via a sub-select if needed.