# Compare a date in CFQUERY to current month

Tags: coldfusion

I am running a cfquery to pull records from a table:

```
<cfquery name="get_followups_monthly" datasource="#datasource#">
    SELECT
        a.DisplayName
        , count(*) AS requested_count
    FROM 
        users AS a 
    INNER JOIN 
        ticket_followup b ON b.requested_by = a.displayName 
    WHERE 
        a.active = 1 AND b.date_of_followup_request < '2022-02-01'
    GROUP BY 
        a.DisplayName
     ORDER BY requested_count DESC
     
</cfquery>
```

I would like to compare the dates returned in column b.date_of_followup_request to see if falls within the current month.

I looked through the [builtin functions](https://helpx-origin.aws116.adobeitc.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-by-category/date-and-time-functions.html) but don't see anything for that. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: First, filtering records in a database requires *sql* functions/operators, not CF functions.  Sql functions are often vendor specific so best to always include your dbms with query questions. Second, what do you mean by "see if it falls within the current month"? Are you trying to retrieve only records for the *current* month? That wouldn't require any functions.

Comment: That is correct. Only for the current month.

Comment: (Edit) You still didn't say which dbms. Filtering doesn't require any functions, just `where col >= X and col < Y`. Determining the current date does. It can be done with sql or CF, whichever you use in your app for datetime functionality. Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983231/coldfusion-mysql-query-within-a-query) (ignore the fact it's a qoq, as the concept still applies). In short, "... filter your query where the item date is >= the fromDate and < fromDate plus 1 month...".